# Converting csv to parquet in spark gives error if csv column headers contain spaces

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have csv file which I am converting to parquet files using databricks library in scala. I am using below code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "local").getOrCreate()
var csvdf = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.csv").option("header", true).csv(csvfile)
csvdf.write.parquet(csvfile + "parquet")
```

Now the above code works fine if I don't have space in my column headers. But if any csv file have spaces in the column headers, it doesn't work and errors out stating invalid column headers. My csv files are delimited by `,`.

Also, I cannot change the spaces of column names of the csv. The column names has to be as they are even if they contain spaces as those are given by end user.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: the parquet file format does not allow for spaces in column names;  
`contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". `  
ORC also does not allow for spaces in column names

Comment: @JamesTobin can you provide this as a resolution to the OP? I think your comment clears it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

per @CodeHunter's request

sadly, the parquet file format does not allow for spaces in column names;
the error that it'll spit out when you try is:  `contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t="`.

ORC also does not allow for spaces in column names :(

Most sql-engines don't support column names with spaces, so you'll probably be best off converting your columns to your preference of `foo_bar` or `fooBar` or something along those lines

Answer (score 2):

I would rename the offending columns in the dataframe, to change space to underscore, before saving. Could be with `select "foo bar" as "foo_bar"` or `.withColumnRenamed("foo bar", "foo_bar")`

Comment: you mean before writing to parquet, right? I thought of that as a solution but I was thinking if there is something that can directly take care of this scenario.

Comment: Yes, I mean before writing to parquet. There may also be some options on quoting / escaping in the csv read that would work, but I'm a) less confident about them and b) tend to prefer names without spaces in my own code, so am projecting!